# How do you configure a Session-Scoped bean to be able to access information from the request and from other services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In order for this session-scoped bean to work, it needs access to the `Request` object to allow it to determine the privileges of the logged-in user.

It also needs to be able to access the `userService` - another bean.

What does it need in order to gain access to these resources?

```
@Configuration
public class ExceptionResolverBuilder 
{
    @Bean @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public ExceptionResolver getExceptionResolver() 
    {

        ExceptionResolver er = new ExceptionResolver();

        User user = userService.getLoggedInUser(request);

        if(user.isAdmin())
        {
            sendEmail("Caught exception:" + exeption.getMessage());
        }
        else
        {
            writeLog("Caught exception:" + exeption.getMessage());              
        }

        return er;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather annoyingly, session-scoped beans don't get easy access to the request that initiated the session.

However, in your case you shouldn't need to.  Assuming that [your `ExceptionResolver` is an implementation of `HandlerExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers), then there's no reason to put your logging logic into `ExceptionResolverBuilder.getExceptionResolver()`, since the resolver will get passed the current `HttpServletRequest` in the `resolveException` method.

Also consider using the `@ExceptionResolver` annotation, which makes life even easier, and also [gets access to the current request](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler).

Answer (score 0):

> In order for this session-scoped bean to work, it needs access to the Request object to allow it to determine the privileges of the logged-in user.

AFAIK, you can only get the current request if it has been passed as a parameter, or via a thread local.

If you are using SpringSecurity, you get the current request's authentication information by calling `SecurityContext.getContext()`.  (This typically uses a thread local.)  However, I'm not sure this will work because your method might be called at a point when the security context hasn't been set.

> It also needs to be able to access the userService - another bean.

You need to arrange that this is provided by dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

For a bean that is defined as a `@Component` you can autowire the HttpServletRequest like so:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class Foo {
    @Autowired private HTTPServletRequest request;

    //
}
```

But since you are using `@Bean` you can't do this.

You can get the current request as follows:

```
    ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest req = sra.getRequest();
```

This uses thread-local under the covers.

If you are using Spring MVC that's all you need.   If you are not using Spring MVC then you will need to register a [RequestContextListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) or [RequestContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) in your `web.xml`.